# 'safe' filter is not working in textarea - django

Tags: javascript, html, django, django-templates

I am showing edit page for what user has given. User gives some text with enter button in textarea and hits preview button. in preview page, he sees just what he has given (i am replacing \n's with `<br>` on the fly).

I am `safe`ing his input like this `{{inputtext|safe}}`. But if he hits edit button, where I render this preview input text, the inputtext is shown like: `text</br></br>text` and not like how it was in preview page.

html in preview:

```
{{inputtext|safe}}
<input type="hidden" name="inputtext" value="{{inputtext}}" />
```

html in input page:

```
<textarea>{{inputtext|safe}}</textarea>
<textarea name="inputtext" style="display: none">{{inputtext}}</textarea>
```

what I do is: take user's input, replace all `\n`'s with `<br/>` and put that new inputtext into the hidden textarea so that i can render this later to preview.

in my views.py, i simply render. nothing much happens there:

```
def addcontent(request):
   if request.POST.get('inputtext'):
       inputtext = request.POST.get('inputtext')
       return render(request, 'addpage.html', {'inputtext':inputtext})
   else:
       return render(request, 'addpage.html', {})
```

Why does not the text show up with linebreaks even if I am safing? I also tried `|linebreaks` but no success

Is there some special case with textarea and safe filter?

**UPDATE**:

If I do `{{inputtext|safe}}` outsife of textarea, it works well (showing up linebreak-ed). only inside of textarea, `|safe` is having no effect somehow

Comment: Could you show the form and the view code? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is that you can't show `html` output in textarea. `linebreaks` just replace linebreaks with `br` and `p` tags.

Why do you replacing linebreaks to `br` in code? If you just want to preview text, but linebreaks is not showing, use css-styles `white-space: pre-wrap` then. This will show text as it was entered.